# Running airplay in simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller, airplay

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [airplay in simulator - objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421841/airplay-in-simulator-objective-c)

How to run AirPlay via iOS simulator?
Like here:
[image]

I setAllowsAirPlay to YES, and run TV-out in simulator, but video doesn't appear

Comment: AirPlay has nothing to do with TV-out.